# Scrolling content sit below main header and nav bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to design a website which on the click of a navigation button, part of the page scrolls while the top header & nav bar stays in place. I have the scrolling working, and the top part stays in place.. but the main content(the part that scrolls) currently sits behind the header & nav bar. The code I have is this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
#Navigation {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10%;
  top: 250px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: x-large;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: medium solid #FFFFFF;
}
#Navigation a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#Navigation a:hover {
  color: #B5B5B5;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#Navigation a:active {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#Header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10%;
  top: 0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="Header">
  Image to Come
</div>
<div id="Navigation">
  <a href="#Introduction" class="nav-link">Introduction</a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#Upcoming-Shows" class="nav-link">Upcoming Shows</a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#Services" class="nav-link">Services</a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#Previous-Shows" class="nav-link">Previous Shows</a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="#Contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
</div>
<div id="Introduction">
  <center>
    <h1>Introduction</h1>
  </center>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ante enim, porta a commodo ac, sodales vel metus. Nulla et magna et augue sagittis volutpat. Pellentesque id est eget eros imperdiet congue et in elit. Aliquam venenatis ullamcorper leo at vehicula.
  Duis vel libero ipsum. Donec eu posuere quam, sit amet posuere risus. Nam malesuada urna id egestas gravida. Aliquam nec imperdiet magna. Nullam interdum, lorem ut sodales molestie, odio ex viverra nunc, vitae tempor orci sem quis ipsum. Ut semper lorem
  sit amet mauris tempus posuere ac et ipsum.
</div>
<div>
  <center>
    <h1 id="Upcoming-Shows">Upcoming Shows</h1>
  </center>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ante enim, porta a commodo ac, sodales vel metus. Nulla et magna et augue sagittis volutpat. Pellentesque id est eget eros imperdiet congue et in elit. Aliquam venenatis ullamcorper leo at vehicula.
  Duis vel libero ipsum. Donec eu posuere quam, sit amet posuere risus. Nam malesuada urna id egestas gravida. Aliquam nec imperdiet magna. Nullam interdum, lorem ut sodales molestie, odio ex viverra nunc, vitae tempor orci sem quis ipsum. Ut semper lorem
  sit amet mauris tempus posuere ac et ipsum.
</div>
<div>
  <center>
    <h1 id="Services">Services</h1>
  </center>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ante enim, porta a commodo ac, sodales vel metus. Nulla et magna et augue sagittis volutpat. Pellentesque id est eget eros imperdiet congue et in elit. Aliquam venenatis ullamcorper leo at vehicula.
  Duis vel libero ipsum. Donec eu posuere quam, sit amet posuere risus. Nam malesuada urna id egestas gravida. Aliquam nec imperdiet magna. Nullam interdum, lorem ut sodales molestie, odio ex viverra nunc, vitae tempor orci sem quis ipsum. Ut semper lorem
  sit amet mauris tempus posuere ac et ipsum.
</div>
<div>
  <center>
    <h1 id="Previous-Shows">Previous Shows</h1>
  </center>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ante enim, porta a commodo ac, sodales vel metus. Nulla et magna et augue sagittis volutpat. Pellentesque id est eget eros imperdiet congue et in elit. Aliquam venenatis ullamcorper leo at vehicula.
  Duis vel libero ipsum. Donec eu posuere quam, sit amet posuere risus. Nam malesuada urna id egestas gravida. Aliquam nec imperdiet magna. Nullam interdum, lorem ut sodales molestie, odio ex viverra nunc, vitae tempor orci sem quis ipsum. Ut semper lorem
  sit amet mauris tempus posuere ac et ipsum.
</div>
<div>
  <center>
    <h1 id="Contact">Contact</h1>
  </center>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ante enim, porta a commodo ac, sodales vel metus. Nulla et magna et augue sagittis volutpat. Pellentesque id est eget eros imperdiet congue et in elit. Aliquam venenatis ullamcorper leo at vehicula.
  Duis vel libero ipsum. Donec eu posuere quam, sit amet posuere risus. Nam malesuada urna id egestas gravida. Aliquam nec imperdiet magna. Nullam interdum, lorem ut sodales molestie, odio ex viverra nunc, vitae tempor orci sem quis ipsum. Ut semper lorem
  sit amet mauris tempus posuere ac et ipsum.
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the top `<div id="Introduction">` sit below the nav bar, and when you scroll have it judge that position as where it needs to scroll to. I have tried everything I can think of, combing `Position: absolute;` and `position: fixed;` a couple `margin-top: **px;` tried putting everything in a `<div id="wrapper"></div>` plus numerous other things I cant recall now.. but nothing seems to work.

Any tips or ideas are much appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

would try to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    hash=  document.location.hash.substr(1);
        if (hash == "Introduction") {
            $("html, body").delay(50).animate({scrollTop: $('#Introduction').offset().top }, 3000);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: where abouts do I put this? when I had it on to the end in th same <script></script> tags it breaks the animation, and if I put it within its own tags nothing changes